# Ubuntu unable to unpack tar.bz2 to /usr/local

Tags: ubuntu, boost, tar

I wan to install boost_1_54_0 in my Ubuntu (10.0+ version). I download the package to /home/Downloas
Then I try to follow the steps given in the official web of boost. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

I input the code

```
~/Downloads$ tar --bzip2 -xf /path/to/boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2
```

Then the error is:

```
tar (child): /path/to/boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So I think maybe I should change the part "/path/to/", but I don't know which I should replace with.

There is a similar question [Installing latest 1.44 boost library under ubuntu 10.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829421/installing-latest-1-44-boost-library-under-ubuntu-10-04), however the guy there successfully finished the first step, which now I get stuck in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it to the path where you've actually *put* your bzip file.

`/path/to` is a meta directory, meant to indicate the path to where the given file is. So, for example, if you've put the file in your system `tmp` directory, you would use `/tmp/boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2`.

In the case where it's in `/home/Downloads`, that's what you'd use. Or, if you're actually *in* the directory where the file is, you can just use the file name without a path.

Answer (score 0):

Yor're right, you should change that part "path/to".
You get the error message: "No such file or directory", which means that there something wrong with your string. 
ANd also. You're already in the map "Downloads" this means that the string should only be "boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2".

Try running this under Downloads:

```
 ~Downloads$ tar --bzip2 -xf boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with your boost_1_77_0.tar.bz2，Try downloading it again.
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.77.0/boost_1_77_0.tar.bz2/download